# How to make retrofit API call using ViewModel and LiveData

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit, android-livedata, android-jetpack

this is the first time I'm trying to implement MVVM architecture, and I'm a bit confused about the correct way to make an API call.

Currently, I'm just trying to make a simple query from the IGDB API, and output the name of the first item in a log.

My activity is setup as follow:

```
public class PopularGamesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_popular_games);


        PopularGamesViewModel popViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PopularGamesViewModel.class);
        popViewModel.getGameList().observe(this, new Observer<List<Game>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Game> gameList) {
                String firstName = gameList.get(0).getName();
                Timber.d(firstName);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My View Model is set up as follow:

```
public class PopularGamesViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private static final String igdbBaseUrl = "https://api-endpoint.igdb.com/";
    private static final String FIELDS = "id,name,genres,cover,popularity";
    private static final String ORDER = "popularity:desc";
    private static final int LIMIT = 30;

    private LiveData<List<Game>> mGameList;

    public PopularGamesViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);


        // Create the retrofit builder
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(igdbBaseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        // Build retrofit
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

        // Create the retrofit client
        RetrofitClient client = retrofit.create(RetrofitClient.class);
        Call<LiveData<List<Game>>> call = client.getGame(FIELDS,
                ORDER,
                LIMIT);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<LiveData<List<Game>>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LiveData<List<Game>>> call, Response<LiveData<List<Game>>> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    Timber.d("Call response body not null");
                    mGameList = response.body();

                } else {
                    Timber.d("Call response body is null");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LiveData<List<Game>>> call, Throwable t) {
                Timber.d("Retrofit call failed");
            }
        });

    }

    public LiveData<List<Game>> getGameList() {
        return mGameList;
    }
```

Now the problem is because this is an API call, the initial value of `mGameList` will be null, until `call.enqueue` returns with a value. This will cause a null pointer exception with

```
popViewModel.getGameList().observe(this, new Observer<List<Game>>() {
```

1. So what is the correct way to handle the observation of a LiveData,
   while API call is being made?
2. Did I perform the Retrofit API call
       in the right place?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are 3 problems in your code.

1. You must create a `MutableLiveData` object because you have an empty response before API call then your `LiveData` object will be filled somehow through the IGDB response.

```
private MutableLiveData<List<Game>> mGameList = new MutableLiveData();
//...
public LiveData<List<Game>> getGameList() {
    return mGameList;
}
```

2. Another mistake is changing the reference of `mGameList` instead of setting its value, So try to change:

```
Timber.d("Call response body not null");
mGameList = response.body();
```

to

```
mGameList.setValue(response.body());
```

3. Calling retrofit inside your `ViewModel` class is avoiding separation of concerns. It's better to create a repository module and get your response through an interface. Read this [article](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) for details.

> Repository modules are responsible for handling data operations. They
>   provide a clean API to the rest of the app. They know where to get the
>   data from and what API calls to make when data is updated. You can
>   consider them as mediators between different data sources (persistent
>   model, web service, cache, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Ive actually noticed my error 1 and 2 before realising your response, so I got that fixed. Thank you for pointing out my error 3, I will go add a repository.

Comment: I think many people have the same problem, you save my life, thanks.

Comment: How can I know from the `View` when the repository data request is finished.

Answer (score 1):

I just inspired by Google's Demo and created a library, which can add LiveData support for Retrofit. The usage is simple:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(LiveDataCallAdapterFactory())
            .build()
            .create(GithubService::class.java)
            .getUser("shawnlinboy").observe(this,
                Observer { response ->
                    when (response) {
                        is ApiSuccessResponse -> {
                          //success response
                        }
                        else -> {
                            //failed response
                        }
                    }
                })
```

The library site:
https://github.com/shawnlinboy/retrofit-livedata-adapter

Answer (score 0):

// sample interface for retrofit

```
public interface GitHubService {
    @GET("users/{user}/repos")
    Call<List<String>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

// ViewModel class

```
public static class MainActivityViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    final GitHubService gitHubService = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);

    // binding to EditText in DataBinding layout
    public final MutableLiveData<String> userName = new MutableLiveData<>();

    // binding to ListView in DataBinding layout
    public final LiveData<List<String>> listLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(userName, (s) -> new MutableLiveData<List<String>>() {
        {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
                gitHubService.listRepos(s).enqueue(new Callback<List<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<String>> call, Response<List<String>> response) {
                        setValue(response.body());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<String>> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    public MainActivityViewModel(@NonNull Application application, SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle) {
        super(application);
    }
}
```